# Keep a record of changing cell values in a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a column that uses VLOOKUP to bring in values from another sheet. I would like to save the previous value of any cell in this column to the corresponding cell in the next column whenever the cell value has changed.
**Example:**
Current values: Cell A1=1, A2=2
If VLOOKUP brings a different value now and A1 becomes 2, the old value of A1 which is 1, should get updated in cell B1. Same goes for any cell in column A.
Since this change can happen 4 to 5 times, I would like this to repeat copying the old values from column B to E whenever there is a change so that there is a record of all previous values.
I looked for some solutions and found some involving VBA but they just worked for a single cell, not a row or did not have a way to repeat the tracking a few times.
Appreciate any help in this. Thanks!

Comment: If I would try simplifying your question in less words, saying that if a change happens in the range of A:A  column, the previous value should be placed in B, then C, followed by D and finally E **of the same row**. Is this understanding correct? If yes, what would you like happening when the A value is changed for the fifth, sixth time and so on?

Comment: Then, is it possible to have more values/formula added to the range to be checked in A:A?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. As part of the task I am working on, I am not expecting any changes after 5 times. But if the VBA code has a way to insert a column & update, that works for me too. I was just thinking maybe that would complicate things more. Let me know if this still does not clear things up.

Comment: I think it can be done as you say, but it would also be possible to **keep only the last four changes**. I mean, if the fifth change will happen, all the old values from B to E will be translated in a way that make B to keep the C value, C to receive D, D to have E value and E to have the new one of A. What would be more convenient for you?

Comment: And you did not answer the clarification question regarding the possibility to extend the existing range in A:A...

Comment: If it's not too complicated, then having the option to handle even more than 4 or 5 changes by inserting additional columns as needed would be nice. Else, the way you have suggested should be good too as long as I have the history of 5 updates.

Comment: Currently, a VLOOKUP populates column A from another sheet. This sheet will get updated daily through a manual process. So when this source sheet changes, the value brought in by VLOOKUP also changes. which is where keeping the history values comes into play. I am not sure what kind of extension you are suggesting here?

Comment: What I proposed did  not offer the history of 5 updates. It only keeps **the last four**. I tried explaining what it means. Then, your explanation about the possibility to extend the A:A range is not clear at all, on my test. **It is only a matter of cells keeping VLOOKUP formulas**... I mean that the code should use a `Static` variable, able to keep the values of an **existing range**. I wanted to know that this range will be extended and if yes, how to proceed, because for not existing memorized values, an empty string will be returned (put in one of the cells in the range B:E)...

Comment: So, can you clarify the above mentioned issues? I never start coding until I clearly understand what is to be done.

Comment: It is inconvenient to want helping and not receive any clarification... Anyhow, I also need to know if it is possible that Vlookup formulas to return "#N/A" error. It is relatively complicated to deal with errors when using arrays...

Comment: I believe we have a huge time zone gap, sorry that I couldn't reply sooner and I really appreciate you trying to help. The column A will not extend to include any additional columns if that's what you mean. It will just keep getting updated based on the VLOOKUP results.

Comment: I can have the VLOOKUP include a IFERROR to handle errors and instead show '0'.

Comment: The code is able to deal with "#N/A" error. It will record it as "N/A"... Did you test it?

Answer (score -2):

Please, test the next code. It uses `Worksheet_Calculate` event. Please, copy the next code in your sheet to be processed code module.

It firstly load the range to be checked (A:A filled range) in a `Static` dictionary. If you need to reset the dictionary, it would be enough to just write "x" (without double quotes) in "F1". It will fill the previous VLOOKUP formula value in the next empty column. If the value in "E" already exists, a new column will be inserted and used for filling the history. The code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Static dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim rngA As Range, Cel As Range, lastRow As Long, arrHist, arrA, firstRow As Long
  Dim arr, lastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, arrNew, colLetter As String
  Dim rngMark As Range, markCol As Long, nrColHist As Long
  Const strMark As String = "Marker"
  
  firstRow = 6: colLetter = "C" 'define the column and start row of the range to be checked
  
  Set rngMark = Me.Range(colLetter & firstRow - 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=strMark, _
                                                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  If Not rngMark Is Nothing Then
      markCol = rngMark.Column: nrColHist = markCol - Range(colLetter & 1).Column - 1
  Else
      MsgBox "No marked column has been found!" & vbCrLf & _
             "The fifth column after the one being checked must be marked.", vbInformation, _
             "Marked column missing": Exit Sub
  End If
  lastRow = Me.Range(colLetter & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).row    'last row of the chosen column
  Set rngA = Me.Range(colLetter & firstRow & ":" & colLetter & lastRow)    'set the range to be checked
  arrHist = Me.Range(rngA.Offset(0, 1), rngA.Offset(0, nrColHist)).Value 'set the array of previous values
  arrA = rngA.Value
  
  'firstly load the range to be checked in the dictionary
  If dict.count = 0 Or UCase(Me.Range("F1")) = "X" Then 'if dict not loaded, or 'x' in cell "F1"
    dict.RemoveAll               'clear the dictionary
    For i = rngA.row To lastRow  'iterate between the real rows of the range to be checked
        dict.Add rngA.cells(i - rngA.row + 1, 1).Address, rngA.cells(i - rngA.row + 1, 1).Value 'load the dictionary
    Next i
    Me.Range("F1").ClearContents                        'clear contents in case of resetting using 'x'
    MsgBox "The dictionary has been loaded and updated..."
  Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      For i = rngA.row To lastRow                            'iterate between the range to be checked rows
        If dict.Exists(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address) Then 'if the cell address exist in dict
            lastCol = Me.cells(i, rngA.Column + nrColHist + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column 'calculate last filled column
            If lastCol = rngA.Column And Me.cells(i, rngA.Column + nrColHist).Value <> Empty Then 'when all history columns are filled
                If CStr(Me.cells(i, colLetter).Value) <> CStr(dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address)) Then 'it acts only if value <> last dict item
                    rngMark.EntireColumn.Insert: lastCol = rngMark.Column - 1
                    Me.cells(i, lastCol).Value = dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address)    ' take the value from dictionary
                    dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address) = Me.Range(colLetter & i).Value 'update the dictionary item value
                End If
            Else                                                          'when not all 4 history columns are filled
                If CStr(Me.cells(i, colLetter).Value) <> CStr(dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address)) Then 'it acts if val <> last array element
                    Me.cells(i, lastCol + 1).Value = dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address) 'fill the last empty history cells
                    dict(Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address) = Me.Range(colLetter & i).Value  'update the dictionary item value
                End If
            End If
        Else
            dict.Add Me.Range(colLetter & i).Address, Me.Range(colLetter & i).Value        'in case of new formula added
        End If
      Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  End If
End Sub
```

**Good to be known**: If your code stops because of an error, you should manually run the `Sub` of the bottom (`EnableMeEvents`). The code stops Calculations, it disables Events and needs to reenable them.

If you do not know how to add the required reference, please, use the next code, prior to run the main (the above one) and then save the workbook:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

**Note**:

This new version inserts a new column if the history number exceeds 4 changes and use it to record the next history data. But **it needs a reference column**. The fifth column after the one keeping the range to be checked must have a header to be recognized by code. The above event uses **"Mark"**. It must exist on the headers row. I mean, on row above `firstRow`. You can adapt the code (The `strMark` constant) to keep any such a marker you want choosing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225723/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-keep-a-record-of-changing-cell-values-in-a-colu).